# Make multicolumn break if the text is too long

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I just learned about LaTeX recently, and I found a problem.

What I want is:

[image]

The text will break in `multicolumn`. What I did is:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{\normalsize E-LEARNING READINESS MEASUREMENT MODEL}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Criteria 1: Facilities and infrastructure for e-learning}} \\
    \hline
    1 & User ICT infrastructure\\
    2 & Internet connectivity\\
    3 & Learning management system\\
    4 & E-learning room\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Criteria 2: Management}} \\
    \hline
    5 & Willingness to invest in e-learning implementation\\
    6 & Learning time for staff\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Criteria 3: Organization of e-learning function/departement}} \\
    \hline
    7 & Informing about available e-learning courses \\
    8 & Organization of the e-learning activity \\
    9 & Preparatory training in the use of computers \\
    10 & Preparatory training in the use of e-learning system\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Criteria 4: Learners characteristics}} \\
    \hline
    11 & Learners have ICT skills \\
    12 & Learners have internet experience \\
    13 & Learners are motivated to take e-learning courses \\
    14 & Learners prefer their learning style \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox{10cm}{In case the organization has already implemented e-learning, but     experiences problems on point of adoption, we have an additional 
    of indicators that can be measured by asking questions to the
    staff members e-learners:}} 
    \hline
    15 & TEST
\end{tabular}
\label{table:TableI}
\end{table}
```

and the result:

[image]

I'm still confused about how to make it break inside a multicolumn command.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you, just learn latex a few days ago, hope you can help me find it out sir... thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
% more space between table rows
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\footnotesize%
\caption{\label{table:TableI}E-LEARNING READINESS MEASUREMENT MODEL}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|C|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C|}{\textbf{Criteria 1: Facilities and infrastructure for e-learning}} \\
    \hline
    1 & User ICT infrastructure\\
    2 & Internet connectivity\\
    3 & Learning management system\\
    4 & E-learning room\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C|}{\textbf{Criteria 2: Management}} \\
    \hline
    5 & Willingness to invest in e-learning implementation\\
    6 & Learning time for staff\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C|}{\textbf{Criteria 3: Organization of e-learning function/departement}} \\
    \hline
    7 & Informing about available e-learning courses \\
    8 & Organization of the e-learning activity \\
    9 & Preparatory training in the use of computers \\
    10 & Preparatory training in the use of e-learning system\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C|}{\textbf{Criteria 4: Learners characteristics}} \\
    \hline
    11 & Learners have ICT skills \\
    12 & Learners have internet experience \\
    13 & Learners are motivated to take e-learning courses \\
    14 & Learners prefer their learning style \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|C|}{In case the organization has already implemented e-learning, but     experiences problems on point of adoption, we have an additional 
    of indicators that can be measured by asking questions to the
    staff members e-learners:}\\
    \hline
    15 & TEST\\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=normalsize]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering\footnotesize%
\caption{\label{table:TableI}E-LEARNING READINESS MEASUREMENT MODEL}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={cX[c]}, 
    width={\linewidth}, 
    vlines,
    cell{1,6,9,14}{1}={c=2}{wd=\linewidth,font=\bfseries},
    cell{19}{1}={c=2}{wd=\linewidth},
    }
    \hline
    Criteria 1: Facilities and infrastructure for e-learning &\\
    \hline
    1 & User ICT infrastructure\\
    2 & Internet connectivity\\
    3 & Learning management system\\
    4 & E-learning room\\
    \hline
    Criteria 2: Management &\\
    \hline
    5 & Willingness to invest in e-learning implementation\\
    6 & Learning time for staff\\
    \hline
    Criteria 3: Organization of e-learning function/departement &\\
    \hline
    7 & Informing about available e-learning courses \\
    8 & Organization of the e-learning activity \\
    9 & Preparatory training in the use of computers \\
    10 & Preparatory training in the use of e-learning system\\
    \hline
    Criteria 4: Learners characteristics &\\
    \hline
    11 & Learners have ICT skills \\
    12 & Learners have internet experience \\
    13 & Learners are motivated to take e-learning courses \\
    14 & Learners prefer their learning style \\
    \hline
    In case the organization has already implemented e-learning, but     experiences problems on point of adoption, we have an additional 
    of indicators that can be measured by asking questions to the
    staff members e-learners: &\\
    \hline
    15 & TEST\\
    \hline
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

Some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just keep learning about LaTex for my research paper, using tabulararray instead of tabularx is something new for me, thanks again!

Comment: @AgusJanardana `tabularray` is a new package, very convenient. Thank you for accepting my answer!